# Complicated NHibernate component mapping

Tags: nhibernate, inheritance, mapping, components

EDIT: I simplified the problem to leave only what really bothers me.

Hello all,

I am trying to make the following mapping.

In my database, I have a table called "ReportRowValue" containg the following columns:

- RowNumber
- ColumnNumber
- <strike>StringValue</strike>
- LongValue
- DateValue
- Value

In my code I want to get a more usable structure by creating <strike>several</strike> two classes from this one table. I guess this should be done using components <strike>and inheritance</strike> but I did not managed to create a working mapping file. What I want in code should look like this:

ReportRow

- RowNumber
- Values (collection of ReportValue below)

ReportValue <strike>(being an abstract class)</strike>

- ColumnNumber
- Value

<strike>ReportValueString / ReportValueLong / ReportValueDate (each one inheriting from ReportValue)</strike>

- Value (each one having a Value property of its one type)

And that's about all!

Does anyone can point me how to create an nhibernate mapping file/files for doing that?

Thanks,

Meigetsu

Answer (score 0):

There is couple of tools that maps and builds class for you one of them is

mygeneration
is the software http://sourceforge.net/projects/mygeneration/

In this page you find the templates that you need to run with the 
softwarehttp://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/TemplateLibrary/Archives/?query=nhibernate

After you have this in the mygeneration tool you only connect to your DB and it will generated for you

Comment: That helps his problem in absolutely no way. If he applies a generator it will not create the class structure he wants.

Comment: "Does anyone can point me how to create an nhibernate mapping file/files for doing that? I'm new to nhibernate and completely lost right now..."
this tool absolute can help him but he need to change some of the mapping and the class after the code generated.

Comment: Let me add a precision : I'm lost only because of this specific mapping. The more classic mappings are not a problem for me (it's even better to right them by hand, so I learn!). Anyway, as sirrocco said, your solution will generate me the classic/simple mapping and not give me any clue on how to seperate the table into several classes.

Thank you anyway for the tool, it could be usefull later!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't have a polymorphic structure in a component. But I'm acutally not sure if you need it.

The following code is straight from my head, so it certainly has errors or missing things and wouldn't compile. But it should show the direction:

```
public class ReportRow
{
  public int Id { get; private set; }
  public IList<IReportValue> Values { get; private set; }
}

public interface IReportValue
{
  public int Id{ get; set; }
  public object UntypedValue { get; }
}

public abstract class ReportValue<T> : IReportValue
{
  public int Id{ get; set; }
  public T Value { get; set; }
  public object UntypedValue { get { return Value; } }
}

public class ReportLongValue : ReportValue<long> {}
public class ReportStringValue : ReportValue<string> {}
public class ReportDateValue : ReportValue<DateTime>{}
```

Mapping:

```
<class ReportRow>
  <id ...>
  <bag name="Values" >
    <key column="RowNumber"/>
    <one-to-many class="IReportValue"/>
  </bag>
</class>

<class name="IReportValue" abstract="true">
  <id ...>
  <subclass name="ReportLongValue">
    <property name="Value" column="LongValue"/>
  </subclass>
  <subclass name="ReportStringValue">
    <property name="Value" column="StringValue"/>
  </subclass>
  <subclass name="ReportDateValue">
    <property name="Value" column="DateValue"/>
  </subclass>
</class>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but that solution would lead to the creation of two different tables in ths database: ReportRow and IReportValue. That excactly what I would like to avoid (having a ReportRow table with only a rownumber seems unnecessary to me).

Comment: That's correct, there are two tables. You could probably avoid it using custom sql for loading and storing. But this is not very straight forward. Where is this ReportRow actually used in? You could probably merge this with a table holding it.

Comment: It is used in a Report table. I don't think it would be a good idea to merge a report and it's rows. ;-)
I got to the conclusion that nhibernate does not allow such structure, so I just gave up and created a two table solution similar to yours.